# Spline interpolation of a binary mask

Tags: image-processing, interpolation

I have the following binary mask (If it helps you can assume that every it is always 1px wide).

[image]

I want to travel from one given point to another (from start to end in this case). You are given the coordinates (green circles) but they're not in any particular order.

A naive way to do is by taking the next closest coordinate, however, it can skip the next coordinate if there is another coordinate that is closer to the current coordinate.

You can assume all non-zero pixels are connected (unlike the given image). How to do that?

Comment: ya, you gotta problem if you have the points (as pairs of numbers) that are not ordered in the curve.  You gotta get them in order.

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on what type of constraints you can put on the problem and what additional information you have: For example "no turns by more than 90 degrees", "max distance between two points is X", etc.

If you have no constraints or knowledge at all that this becomes the "travelling sales man" problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Answer (score 0):

What you could build is an iterative model in a Dynamic Programing fashion.

Then you could build some "reward" to pass through given points.
This reward will regularize the path and prevent skipping points.

The delicate thing is to optimize the reward versus the cost of longer path. Yet using some cross validation you'll be able to find the right balance.